# After adding react-router-dom following error is shown by Parcel

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, parceljs

When I added react-router-dom in my react project following error is thrown when it is built using parcel. How can I solve this?

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:
(0, _assert().default)(node.type === 'file')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, after deleting the .parcel-cache folder and then re-run the project, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please try and removing tags with empty attributes, example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
```

Ref: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/discussions/5385

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. There are no such empty tags inside my react project.

Comment: Are there any extra errors in your stack trace? maybe where the error is originating from?

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. After deleting the .parcel-cache folder it worked.

Comment: Glad that worked! That suggestion was also in the reference! Make sure to submit an answer and mark it as your accepted answer for future visitors!